# How to add an optional positional group of arguments using Python argeparse module?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to achieve argument declaration just like the [GNU timeout utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation):

`timeout [option] duration command [arg]…`

Here, the `option` could be any number of *option arguments*, you should pass them before `duration` and `command`, and they are optional. How you can achieve this using Python `argparse`?

Help output:

```bash
[user@desktop ~]# timeout --help
Usage: timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
  or:  timeout [OPTION]
Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
      --preserve-status
                 exit with the same status as COMMAND, even when the
                   command times out
      --foreground
                 when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,
                   allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals;
                   in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
  -k, --kill-after=DURATION
                 also send a KILL signal if COMMAND is still running
                   this long after the initial signal was sent
  -s, --signal=SIGNAL
                 specify the signal to be sent on timeout;
                   SIGNAL may be a name like 'HUP' or a number;
                   see 'kill -l' for a list of signals
  -v, --verbose  diagnose to stderr any signal sent upon timeout
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

Comment: In argparse docs those are called `optionals`, and use a dashed flag, `-f` or `--foo`.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I know! But my question is how you can group them in one positional argument (here called `OPTION`). In the example above, you cannot use `-k` after `DURATION` or `COMMAND`.

Comment: argparse groups the optionals at the start in the `usage`, but does not enforce this when parsing.

Comment: argparse does not group arguments.  While positionals parsed in a particular order (by 'position'), optionals can occur in any order (and even repeatedly).  You may need to change `DURATION` and `COMMAND` to being flagged arguments, since they aren't required all the time.  While argparse tries to conform to POSIX standards, it can't be used to duplicate every UNIX/Linux function; And GNU has its own parsing practices.